# Setup for PHP with FileMaker Server on Windows 7 and Apache Server

Tags: filemaker

I'm trying to get PHP Web Publishing working with FMS 11.0.2.217 on Windows 7 and apache server. I've clicked the link on Filemaker Server Admin Console for PHP.  The Filemaker PHP Site Assistant launches, I select Create New Site and enter Test as name and enter server ip and click connect.  I receive the following error:
 "Publishing engine is not running on the specified server"
Also in the FileMaker Server Admin Console >General Settings it does not hold the "Automatically start web publishing engine" check box after I click it and save.  It does accept and hold "Automatically start Database Server"

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4):

Go to this URL in a browser like FireFox that supports XML rendering:

http://yourServerAddress/fmi/xml/FMPXMLRESULT.xml?-dbnames

You should get an XML listing of all of the databases on your server. If you get something else, then your Web Publishing Engine is not installed correctly, or is not running. In that case, I would recommend uninstalling and re-installing the Web Publishing Engine, or call FileMaker tech support.

Comment: Instead of 'yourServerAddress' what should I write??? either 'localhost' address or 'Admin Console' adress

Comment: Put the IP address of the computer where you ran the Web Publishing Engine installer.

Answer (score 1):

Also be well aware that FMS does NOT support Apache on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Just a word of warning with FileMaker server / PHP -- ensure that your web application isn't high concurrent volume or you're going to have problems.

FileMaker Server has a very limited number of concurrent connections and the timeout value on requests makes using FileMaker Server problematic if you have a large number of concurrent sessions.